# Cypress, javascript: dayjs does not return current date correctly

Tags: javascript, datetime, cypress, dayjs, cypress-dayjs

I am coding cypress tests. I use cypress v10.3.0.

I am getting a wrong date when I use dayjs function for the second time.

```
var dayjs = require('dayjs')
cy.log(dayjs(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'))
cy.wait(5000)
cy.log(dayjs(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'))
```

Output picture:

[output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2jnn.png)

output text (same text as in the picture):

1. log 13/07/2022 10:20:24
2. wait 5000
3. log 13/07/2022 10:20:24

First log is ok, but second log should be: 13/07/2022 10:25:24

Why is the first and second log the same?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the expected output.

Reason is, `cy.log()` (both lines) takes it's value before the commands run, before the `cy.wait()` happens.

You can change it to this

```js
cy.log(dayjs(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'))
cy.wait(5000)
cy.then(() => {
  cy.log(dayjs(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'))  //wait to take value
})
```

to see 5 seconds (approx) difference.

The `cy.then()` wrapper delays setting up the log command, and delays evaluating `dayjs(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss')` until after the `cy.wait()` has run.